# how to make JButton show a list of JButtons with just few items

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Hey Guys my problem is when I place the mouse on a JButton in my JFrame, I want it to show a list of JButtons on its left.

[image]

I don't known how to do that really I feel like I'm blocked and I cant make any progress in my project.

I'd would be grateful if you could help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the picture you uploaded?

Comment: Could you explain in greater detail what you're trying to do and where you're stuck?

Comment: I want to when I place the mouse on the first JButton for example it list of items associated to it. you understand me now?

Comment: No, not really. Are you desiring to set the JButton's tooltips? You really need to spend a little time and work on giving us the details of your problem. You're glossing over things too much I'm afraid.

Comment: what is a tooltips?!

I want to perfom something like the JPopupMenu but with a JButton

Comment: [Tooltips Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html), but again, let's move away from this painful and frustrating game of our trying to pry information from you, and you giving us small tiny incomplete bits. If you want someone to put in the effort of giving you a full answer, please put in the effort of asking a complete and thorough question.

Comment: they did understand me.

Comment: Please come again? Who understood you?

Comment: If needed, consider using a CardLayout and a MouseListener...

Answer (score 0):

Can you create the list of buttons in a `JPanel`, add it to your `JFrame` and then call `myPanel.setVisible(false)`.  When you click your button then call `myPanel.setVisible(true)`?

As for ensuring that `myPanel` is positioned correctly you will want to use a [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Or is there a more complex behaviour you want?

Comment: not that much I will try this and I will tell you if it works @Richard

Answer (score 0):

A basic option would be to use a [`MouseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).  The `MouseListener` would be used to determine when the mouse cursor enters/exists a given component and the `CardLayout` would be used to display the appropriate sub component for each "menu" element.

I have to say, `JButton` would be me last choice for the "menu" item, in most cases, a `JLabel` would be preferred or even perhaps using a `JMenu`, which can can have sub menus, which can be displayed automatically might be a better choice, or even a `JComboBox`....

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ShowStuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ShowStuff();
    }

    public ShowStuff() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                MenuPane menu = new MenuPane();
                menu.addMenu("Fruit", new FruitPane());
                menu.addMenu("Meat", new MeatPane());
                menu.addMenu("Dairy", new DairyPane());

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(menu);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MenuPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel subMenu;
        private JPanel menu;
        private CardLayout cardLayout;
        private MouseListener mouseHandler;

        public MenuPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            cardLayout = new CardLayout();
            subMenu = new JPanel(cardLayout);

            menu = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            add(subMenu);
            add(menu, BorderLayout.WEST);

            subMenu.add(new JPanel(), "BLANK");

            mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
                        cardLayout.show(subMenu, btn.getText());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    cardLayout.show(subMenu, "BLANK");
                }

            };
        }

        public void addMenu(String name, JPanel subMenuPane) {
            JButton button = new JButton(name);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            menu.add(button, gbc);
            subMenu.add(subMenuPane, name);
            button.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
        }

    }

    public abstract class ButtonPane extends JPanel {

        private int gridy = 0;

        public ButtonPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        }

        protected void addButton(String name) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(name);
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = gridy++;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class FruitPane extends ButtonPane {

        public FruitPane() {
            addButton("Banana");
            addButton("Grapes");
            addButton("Apples");
            addButton("Tomatoes");
        }

    }

    public class MeatPane extends ButtonPane {

        public MeatPane() {
            addButton("Lamb");
            addButton("Beef");
            addButton("Pork");
            addButton("Mince");
        }

    }

    public class DairyPane extends ButtonPane {

        public DairyPane() {
            addButton("Milk");
            addButton("Cream");
            addButton("Cheese");
            addButton("Yoghurt");
        }

    }

}
```